# Carrierwave resize existing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a rails 3 application which uses the CarrierWave gem. Until now, I have uploaded my pictures in 48*48 and 100*100 but now I would like to store them in 200*200.

Is there a way to resize my already uploaded images ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to add you new version to the image uploader...

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
end
```

...and then recreate them:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.avatar.recreate_versions!
end
```

See [carrierwave's readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop/resize every pictures:

```
MyModel.where.not(picture: nil).each{|v| v.picture.resize_to_fill(150, 150)}
```

/!\ It will **replace** the original picture.